# Trying to keep session with curl login in twitter

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies, twitter

I'm trying to keep the session along different requests with curl when login into twitter because at some point it logs out from Twitter

```
$sTarget = "https://twitter.com";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie". $usuario ."_tweet.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $usuario ."_tweet.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
           echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
        }

preg_match('<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)">', $html, $match);

$authenticity_token = $match[1];

if ($authenticity_token == "");
{       
preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $matchprima);   
$authenticity_token = $matchprima[1];
}


$username = $usuario;
$password = "*******";

$sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
# display server response
$htmldos = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $htmldos, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);


if(curl_errno($ch))
{
   echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

But when doing a `var_dump` in cookies to see if the cookies values are the same, under `["_twitter_sess"]` I get different strings in the 2 requests. Shouldn't I get the same string if the session is kept between requests? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: So, you are just trying to login with this curl post correct? If so, then you are getting 2 different cooking because twitter thinks it's a new session that is wanting to be created.

Comment: I can login, but at some point it logs out

Comment: The code is much larger than that

Comment: Does twitter have a timeout? I'm trying to help work through this since I have never worked with Twitter this way.

Comment: what's this? Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp64\www\twitterlogin\index.php on line 35

Comment: in this line ` $authenticity_token = $match[1];`

Comment: if nobody figures it out by 3rd july, feel free to send me an email linking to this thread

Comment: Do you need something particulary to this code? I think I might have a code working and running for logging in Twitter somewhere now, which doesnt log out (not sure but I might take a look if that's what you need) . And for this code, I dont remember why it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for logging in Twitter, and keeping session as for doing other things such after it as sending tweets. I've been using it for 6 months without problem. You need simple_html_dom.php from [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for it to work

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

global $usuario;
$usuario = "universohumor2"; //your twitter account username

$ch = curl_init();  

/************************************** COMIENZAN LAS LLAMADAS A FUNCIONES *************************************/
/***************************************************************************************************************/

$vector_retorno = logueo_twitter($ch);


/******************************************************************************************************************/

function logueo_twitter($ch)
{

    //$ch = curl_init();

    global $usuario;

    $sTarget = "https://twitter.com";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie". $usuario ."_tweet.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);

      if(curl_errno($ch))
            {
               echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
            }

    preg_match('<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)">', $html, $match);

    $authenticity_token = $match[1];

    if ($authenticity_token == "");
    {       
    preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $matchprima);   
    $authenticity_token = $matchprima[1];
    }


    $username = $usuario;
    $password = "password"; // your twitter account password

    $sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

    $sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    # display server response
    $htmldos = curl_exec($ch);

    //echo $htmldos;

    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
       echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    $vector["sPost"] = $sPost;
    $vector["authenticity_token"] = $authenticity_token;

    return $vector;

}

?>
```

Comment: good job! but you're doing the HTML parsing so damn wrong, its painful. for your own sake, please learn how to use DOMDocument and DOMXpath, they're much more reliable than regex-parsing of html. also, your $aPath code is bugged, you forget to urlencode $username and $password and $authenticity_token , so if any of them contains spaces, or `ÆØÅ` or `& =` or a bunch of other characters, it wont work.

Comment: here is a cleaned up version, please check it out, you could learn from it: https://pastebin.com/J1gkyj1j